# MSSQL Passthrough Database options?

Tags: sql-server, passthrough

Is there an option out there to create a MSSQL Database that is a passthrough of a sort?

To give the scenario we are in, we have one central large database that is a copy of production that is used for several different teams to develop on.  I would like to create a local database that links to the development server where I can keep my versions of updated procs until they are ready to go to the shared server.

I know I would have to fully qualify any table queries and so on, but would like to know if I can set something so that if a proc didn't exist locally, it would fall through to the development server to execute the proc there?  That way i can point my development code to my local DB instance and execute what I do have locally, what I don't have remotely and not have to copy/clone a very large database that is refreshed from a prod snapshot on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to go here is implement source control and pulls from source control to keep your local copy of the database up-to-date with regards to stored procedures and functions. There are plenty of 3rd party tools that help keep you synchronized with regards to this sort of thing. That would mean you're only pulling down and updating the code changes and not restoring a whole snapshot.

This also works in reverse with these tools as you can push code up to source control from your local copy. Then it can be incorporated into a build and applied to that central DB.